# SSRS 2008 - Error opening Report that has subreports in Report Manager - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, object-reference, subreports

This is the scenario.

A report was working fine in SSRS 2005. It has 4 subreports, one of which has two subreports.

The server got upgraded to 2008 (not R2). Now the reports returns

```
>An error occurred during client rendering.
>An error has occurred during report processing.
>Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

After some debugging and playing around, I found that the report works if I remove the subreports. All of them use just one parameter, which is being sent from one of the main dataset fields (userID).

Weird thing is that, testing this same report in another report Server which is 2008 R2, the report works perfectly...

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: It could be something as simple as the Datasource not being set correctly?  To get a better understanding of what the problem is check the logs. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Answer (score -1):

I'm in 2015, but same problem. Turned out my report had a space as the last character of its name. Removed that and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing from a shared Dataset to an embedded Dataset. I say this because after struggling the whole day with this error and resolving it by redoing my drillthrough report which took me about 45 minutes. I just inadvertently recreated this error. This happened when I changed one of my main reports from referencing an embedded dataset to a shared dataset because I did not want to have embedded code if the code was used by multiple reports. Note, this shared dataset is not a stored procedure, the code is inside Visual Studio, I am not sure if this has anything to do with it. Just thought I should mention that. Anyways I resolved this issue by copying the code and reverting back to an embedded dataset and the error was gone.